# Improve Access Module and Eliminate Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, module, vba, format

I am creating a procedure for identifying the detailed lines from `tbl_a` that are creating an abnormal balance at the `tbl_a.LevelA` level and inserting identified lines into `tbl_d`.

Once a month, I import the closing account balances into `tbl_a.LevelA`, `tbl_a.LevelB`, `tbl_a.AMOUNT`.

From there, I have code set up to determine whether the current balance is a debit or credit, update the normal balance from a reference table (`tbl_b`), and identify whether the detail line balance is abnormal.

I also have had to create a separate select query to identify whether the balance is abnormal at the `LevelA` level.  I use this information to identify all line items that are abnormal at `LevelA` and `LevelB`.

My import, code, query, and desired output is given below:

**Import**

[image: Import]

**Code**

```vb
Private Sub Edit()

Dim MsgTitleImport As String

MsgTitleImport = "xxx"

Set MyDb = CurrentDb()

DoCmd.Hourglass False
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'qry_a
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_a " & _
        "INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.LEVELA = tbl_b.LEVELA " & _
        "SET tbl_a.NORMAL = tbl_b.NORMAL " & _
        "WHERE tbl_a.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_b
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_a " & _
        "SET tbl_a.CURRENT = iif([tbl_a.AMOUNT]>=0,'POSITIVE','NEGATIVE') " & _
        "WHERE tbl_a.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_c
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_a " & _
        "SET tbl_a.ABNORMAL_B = iif([tbl_a.CURRENT]=[tbl_a.NORMAL],'N','Y') " & _
        "WHERE tbl_a.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_d
MySQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_c (LEVELA, AMOUNT) " & _
        "SELECT qry_d.LEVELA, qry_d.AMOUNT " & _
        "FROM qry_d;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_e
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_c " & _
        "INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_c.LEVELA = tbl_b.LEVELA " & _
        "SET tbl_c.NORMAL = tbl_b.NORMAL " & _
        "WHERE tbl_c.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_f
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_c " & _
        "SET tbl_c.CURRENT = iif([tbl_c.AMOUNT]>=0,'POSITIVE','NEGATIVE') " & _
        "WHERE tbl_c.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_g
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_c " & _
        "SET tbl_c.ABNORMAL_A = iif([tbl_c.CURRENT]=[tbl_c.NORMAL],'N','Y') " & _
        "WHERE tbl_c.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_h
MySQL = "UPDATE tbl_a " & _
        "INNER JOIN tbl_c ON tbl_a.LEVELA = tbl_c.LEVELA " & _
        "SET tbl_a.ABNORMAL_A = tbl_c.ABNORMAL_A " & _
        "WHERE tbl_a.LEVELA Is Not Null;"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

'qry_i
MySQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_d (LEVELA, LEVELB, AMOUNT, CURRENT, NORMAL, ABNORMAL_A, ABNORMAL_B) " & _
        "SELECT tbl_a.LEVELA, tbl_a.LEVELB, tbl_a.AMOUNT, tbl_a.CURRENT, tbl_a.NORMAL, tbl_a.ABNORMAL_A, tbl_a.ABNORMAL_B " & _
        "FROM tbl_a " & _
        "WHERE tbl_a.ABNORMAL_A = 'Y' AND tbl_a.ABNORMAL_B = 'Y';"
MyDb.Execute MySQL

DoCmd.Hourglass False

MsgBox "xxx", vbOKOnly, MsgTitleImport

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

**Query**

```
SELECT tbl_b.LEVELA, Sum(tbl_a.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM tbl_a INNER JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.LEVELA = tbl_b.LEVELA
WHERE (((tbl_b.LEVELA) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY tbl_b.LEVELA;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

I had a couple questions:

1. Is there any way to add the separate query (`qry_d`) to the module code?
2. Is there a better format to use for this code?  This is the first database that I have built, so I am not sure how this should look if done "properly".

Thanks in advance for your help.